# Отправить данные(таблицу) в outlook?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, outlook

Добрый день, есть приложение в котором есть формуляр. Его мы наполняем данными и хотим отправить письмом некоторым пользователям. Что хотим реализовать: чтобы человек открыл письмо в outlook(!) и там в body была таблица с данными, которые мы послали. Перенести html table через mailto нельзя, какие есть способы подобного решения? Как автоматизировать, чтобы кажыдй раз в ручную не создавать таблицу там и не вписывать данные.
Спасибо

Comment: mailto протокол имеет "лимит" на колличество символов. Поэтому таблица туда при всём желании не поместится.

Comment: @nick_n_a ну именно.

Comment: Используйте библиотеки для работы с smtp протоколом (указав параметры mail-сервера отправки). Письмо можно отправить только от имени сервера. В вложении можно добавить html с таблицей. Но отправка будет выглядеть совсем иначе чем по mailto протоколу.

Comment: В outlook при помощи ASP NET вы никак такое письмо не передадите. Ответ на вопрос "в таком виде - никак".

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо за совет.